# AWS Redshift Spectrum not working with apache parquet files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

following is my sample csv file.

```
id,name,gender
1,isuru,male
2,perera,male
3,kasun,male
4,ann,female
```

i converted above csv file into apache parquet using pandas library. following is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv('./data/students.csv')
df.to_parquet('students.parquet')
```

after that i uploaded the parquet file into the s3 and created a external table like below.

```
create external table imp.s1 (
id integer,
name varchar(255),
gender varchar(255)
)
stored as PARQUET 
location 's3://sample/students/';
```

after that i just run select query, but i got following error.

```
select * from imp.s1

Spectrum Scan Error. File 'https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sample/students/students.parquet' 
has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 's3://sample/students.id'. 
Column type: INT, Parquet schema:\noptional int64 id [i:0 d:1 r:0] 
(s3://sample/students.parquet)
```

**Could you please help me to figure out what's the problem in here ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For NULLable integer values, Pandas use the dtype Int64 that correspond to [Bigint](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powerexchange-adapters-for-informatica/10-2-2/powerexchange-for-amazon-s3-user-guide/appendix-a--amazon-s3-datatype-reference/parquet-amazon-s3-file-data-types-and-transformation-data-types.html) in Parquet Amazon S3.

| Parquet Amazon S3 File Data Type | Transformation | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Int32 | Integer | -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (Precision of 10, scale of 0) |
| Int64 | Bigint | -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (Precision of 19, scale of 0) |

You need to explicitly set the column type of `id` when calling [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/students.csv', dtype={'id': 'int32'})
```